# how to prevent a duplicate record in SQLite or How To check if the record already exist

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to insert a place in a table named `favoriteList` but if the record exists I want to avoid duplicate record

```cs
private void ADD_TO_FAVORITES_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Fav = new favoriteList();
    Fav.Name_OF_Place = nameplace.Text;
    Fav.Image_OF_Place = imgplace.Source.ToString();
    Fav.Basic_Info = basic.Text;
    Fav.USERID = UserId;
    Fav.Place_ID = PlaceId;
    _Crud = new Crud_on_user();
    var a =_Crud.GetAllListNote(UserId);

    // Does not Work
    bool b = a.Contains<favoriteList>(Fav);
    if ()
    {
        DisplayAlert("Sorry", " Item Already exists", "ok");
        return; 
    }
    else
    {
        _Crud.InsertDetails(Fav);
        DisplayAlert("added", " Item was added", "ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: your `Fav` is **new** `favoriteList` instance it is not stored in `a` for sure

Comment: You are comparing objects where you may rather want to compare against a key instead. For example: `bool b = a.Any(f => f.Place_ID.Equals(Fav.Place_ID))`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is that `Contains` check if objects are the same. As `a` is List from `_Crud` for sure it does not contain `Fav`.

What I would suggest is that you should check against IDs. Based on your implementation it can be:

`bool hasAlreadyFavourites = a.Any(f => f.USERID.Equals(Fav.USERID))`

If I can suggest something, try to work on the naming of variables so they can be more meaningful. `a`, `b` or even `Fav` are not the best names

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions Thank you!